# Beamer - Wide Example Box

Tags: beamer, width, block

I am using this code to get an untitled example block.

```
\begin{exampleblock}{}
\end{exampleblock}
```

As we know, this box has a width equal to the text width. How can I modify the code to get a box that spans over the entire page as shown below ?

[image: Beamer box]

Any suggestion on this would be really helpful to me...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: You are correct... This will be kept in mind... Thank you...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package to easily create your box (you can use the `beamer` skin). Setting the desired width for the box (and the text width inside the box) is just a matter of setting the appropriate keys. A little example; since the original `beamer` theme used was not specified in the question, I defined my own colors to emulate the original ones; adjust the settings according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,112,214}
\makeatletter
\newtcolorbox{tcbexample}[1][]{
  skin=beamer,
  enhanced,
  title=#1,
  width=\paperwidth,
  left=\Gm@lmargin,
  right=\Gm@rmargin,
  enlarge left by=-\Gm@lmargin,
  enlarge right by=-\Gm@rmargin,
  arc=0pt,
  outer arc=0pt,
  colback=myblue,
  boxrule=0pt,
  colupper=white,
  colbacktitle=myblue!40!black
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tcbexample}
Some test text.
\end{tcbexample}
\begin{tcbexample}[A box with title]
Some longer test text that will span more than a line to illustrate text wrapping.
\end{tcbexample}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]